# ARM/DSP Linux toolchain kernel setup

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, gnu-toolchain, ti-dsp

We have a project that requires a setup with an environment to develop embedded system as host on FC17 AMD64 and target ARM/DSP Omap l138.

So, the kernel headers have to be generated in order to bind the development environment communication between host and target. Thus, it was installed:

```
# yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
# yum install binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel
```

Steps to build:

```
# cd /usr/src/kernels/3.4.4-5.fc17.x86_64/kernel
# ls 
debug  events  gcov  irq  Kconfig.freezer  Kconfig.hz  Kconfig.locks  Kconfig.preempt  Makefile  power  sched  time  trace

# make ARCH=ARM headers_check
make: *** No rule to make target `headers_check'.  Stop.

# make ARCH=ARM INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/home/user/dev/omap/ headers_install;
make: *** No rule to make target `headers_check'.  Stop.
```

Any suggestion what might be the problem?

All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should cross compile the kernel meant for the ARM target. The people where you bought the ARM target should include this in a board support package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine your Makefile, it seems that headers_check is not defined in it.
Maybe "make help" will be useful to you.

Just my 5 cents.